# Is there a way to write a selector that will traverse the parentage of a tag until it finds a match?

Tags: jquery

It doesn't look like there's a way to do this in jQuery, but I thought I'd ask you fine folks if there's a clever work around that will let me avoid `parent().parent().parent()` .

I'm basically looking to accomplish something like this: `$('#myId').parent('li')`

Comment: you mean like [.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)?

Comment: @MrOBrian Should have added it as an answer. You were first. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) selector

```
$('#myId').closest('li');
```

This will traverse up its ancestors in the DOM tree..

[Check FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FLLP5/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `closest()`:

```
$(startElem).closest(selectorString);
```

Or, possibly `parents()`:

```
$(startElem).parents(selectorString);
```

The main difference is that `closest()` will return zero or one matches (the first element it finds, or no elements if the selector doesn't match an ancestor), whereas `parents()` will return one, none or many elements (it continues up the DOM tree to the root element and returns all the found matches (if any).)

Incidentally, `closest()` will also search the starting-element, whereas `parents()` will only look at those ancestors starting from the starting-element's `parent()` node.

References:

- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/).

Comment: @Yatrix: thanks! I can't believe I missed that... *sigh* Clearly, it's been a *long* day! =)

Comment: It's Friday, dude. If you were thinking clearly this late on a Friday, I'd accuse you of being a robot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `closest`  or  `parents`.

The difference is that `parents` returns all parents `li`, `closest` returns the first.

*References*:

- http://api.jquery.com/closest/
- http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('#myId').parents('li')`. See: http://api.jquery.com/parents/